# Как искусственно вызвать событие?

Tags: c#, wpf

Как мне искусственно вызвать событие нажатия левой клавиши мыши на элементе?

**UPD:**

Создаю панель вкладок chrome like. Когда вытаскиваю вкладку из панели, для нее создается новое окно и выполняется метод DragMove(). То есть перемещение окна. Только вот когда вытаскиваю вверх, сразу попадаю за клиентскую область окна и левая клавиша мыши становится отжатой и DragMove() вызывает исключение, говоря, что левая клавиша должна быть нажата.

**UPD2:**

Нашел способ, но он не помогает

```
var arg = new MouseButtonEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice, 0, MouseButton.Left);
arg.RoutedEvent = UIElement.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUpEvent;
CurrentWindow.RaiseEvent(arg);
```

`Mouse.LeftButton` все равно в отжатом состоянии (*== MouseButtonState.Released*)

Comment: А с какой целью вы хотите это сделать?

Comment: @AndrewPrigorshnev, Создаю панель вкладок chrome like. Когда вытаскиваю вкладку из панели, для нее создается новое окно и выполняется метод *DragMove()*. То есть перемещение окна. Только вот когда вытаскиваю вверх, сразу попадаю за клиентскую область окна и левая клавиша мыши становится отжатой и *DragMove()* вызывает исключение, говоря, что левая клавиша должна быть нажата

Comment: _"попадаю за клиентскую область окна и левая клавиша мыши становится отжатой"_ -- а Mouse.Capture вызывали?

Comment: @Stack, да уже неактуально. С захватом мыши у меня проблемы были, поэтому отказался от него. В итоге к нему вернулся и проблемы решил )